# Reproducing a bug in Qt: Segmentation fault when debugging code

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, segmentation-fault, vmware

I am new to Linux, Qt, and relatively junior in C++; so the problem I experience is very likely to be my own fault... Any help is very much appreciated.

I encounter a Segmentation Fault when trying to go step by step in basically any project. For instance, the **tablemodel project included in QtCreator**. In release or in debug, the projects runs without any problem. But if I try adding breakpoints (in debug of course) and stepping through the code, I quickly get the following random error:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.
>
> Signal name : 
>   SIGSEGV
>   Signal meaning : 
>   Segmentation fault

QtCreator at that point shows some small assembly code:

```
        Dump of assembler code for function __nptl_death_event:
0x00e80d00  <+0>:               push   %ebp
0x00e80d01  <+1>:               mov    %esp,%ebp
0x00e80d03  <+3>:               pop    %ebp
0x00e80d04  <+4>:               ret
        End of assembler dump.
```

I am running :

> Qt Creator 2.1.0  Based on Qt 4.7.2 (32 bit)
>   on Ubuntu 11.04 via VMWare on a Mac.

I don't know if VMWare can be a potential source of problem. I suspect I might also be doing something wrong when debugging because I don't understand the external / attach terms ( I haven't had the time to do some research on that yet, so many things to discover at the sametime, a bit overwhelming...)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And if you don't use wmware? If you run on a PC running ubuntu?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any PC available at hand to try this...

Comment: Does this use gdb on windows? I've had similar issues with NetBeans and trying to debug Qt applications. I moved to a new environment and the issue disappeared. I assume it was a version incompatibility but I don't have any particular culprit in mind.

Comment: this is using gdb, but on ubuntu via vmware on a mac, not windows. My version of gdb is: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a problem with you copy of GDB - more specifically, a module or library mismatch.
Try recompiling GDB so that you know it will work with your local glibc and pthreads libraries.

As a side note, that assembly code is an empty function. It sets up a stack frame, tears it right back down again, and returns. It appears to use the cdecl calling convention, which implies the library it was written in is C (rather than C++ )

Comment: Josh, thanks for your help.
As far as I know, I don't think that I have compiled my own version of gdb during my installation process. Would there be an easy way to make sure the problem seems to come from there before getting into this recompiling thing? I'm a bit scared about it because it seems a bit out of my reach / an easy way to break my setup... I hope I'm wrong on this :)

Comment: Did you get the package from the 11.04 repositores, did you have it and then upgraded to 11.04, or did you download from Qt's website?

Comment: You may also want to run ldd on GDB and libpthread and look to see if the object's dependancy versions match - just a hunch

Comment: Thanks for your help Josh, it's much appreciated :) Sorry I don't have the necessary reputation to vote your answers up yet. Hopefully I'll be able to come back on this thread and do that sometime soon.

Comment: ldd on gdb gives:
`linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x001b8000)
 libreadline.so.6 => /lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x006df000)
 libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00f21000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00de1000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00110000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0078c000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00baf000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00cf1000)
 libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x007a8000)
 libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00136000)`

Comment: `libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0026b000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00c1d000)
 libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00741000)
 libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x003cc000)`

Comment: Also, I could not locate a libpthread ; only a .a and a .so ... seems like I did smth wrong installing my system. Will look into that.